# 16 Colors in ZShell

Tags: terminal, zsh, colors

I only seem to be able to call 8 colors in my zshell prompt.

Example:

```
PROMPT="[%n@%{$fg[magenta]%}%m%{$reset_color%} %.]
%# "
```

Works fine. However,

```
PROMPT="[%n@%{$fg[brmagenta]%}%m%{$reset_color%} %.]
%# "
```

Doesn't work. Basically, none of the "bright" color variations appear.

After doing some research, I found that zsh's colors are called by the "colors" setopt.

doing

```
echo ${(o)color}
```

yields this output:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 07 08 22 23 24 25 27 28 30 30 30 30 31 31 32 32 33 33 34 34 35 35 36 36
37 37 39 39 40 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 49 bg-black bg-blue bg-cyan bg-default bg-green
bg-magenta bg-red bg-white bg-yellow black blink blue bold conceal cyan default faint green
magenta no-blink no-conceal no-reverse no-standout no-underline none normal red reverse
standout underline white yellow
```

As you can see, only the standard 8 colors are available. I've tried using the "bg-" variants, which also leave the output as the default text color.

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated. I could, of course, just use one of the normal colors, but then I'd learn nothing!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What terminal emulator are you using?  You can check the number of supported colors by running `echotc Co`.  For example, my `urxvt` supports 88 colors, but `xterm` supports only 8, and bright variations are not included.

If I run it in `urxvt` I get:

```
# Dark magenta/violet:
PS1="[%F{34}%n%F{reset}@%F{magenta}%m%F{reset} %.] " 
# Bright Thistle purple:
PS1="[%F{54}%n%F{reset}@%F{magenta}%m%F{reset} %.] "
```

Sources: `man zshall`

Answer (score 5):

All “colors” you are talking about are just escape sequences in a form `\e[{color_code}m`. Zsh function `colors` does nothing more then adding a few zsh associative array variables mapping human-readable color names to terminal escape sequences. Thus you can either directly use

```
PS1=%{$'\e[54m'%}...
```

or try out @Mischa Arefiev’s answer, it is more readable. Note that escape sequences work in any shell, while constructions like `%F{54}...` work only in zsh.